# How can I include PHP files if the file that I'm going to include is located outside the folder of my current PHP file

Tags: php, file, directory, include, include-path

How can I include PHP files if the file that I'm going to include is located outside the current directory of my php file. It works when I include the the whole directory for example

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\samplephpfile.php';
```

But I know that it is not efficient to use if I uploaded my site in the web server. Help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a root path and then use only `ROOT_PATH`. If you will want to change it you can do it only at one place.

```
define('ROOT_PATH', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `../` to go back one directory, use `/` to go to root directory.

[This article](http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/) explain this idea further.

Comment: Is it okay if I used `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` ? I think it will not result an error if i uploaded it on the web browser.

Comment: Yes, of course you can, the article illustrates how to use it.

Comment: Just wanna ask, I used the above code in my website logo but it's not appearing

Comment: `<?php
$icon =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/empc/images/icon.png"; 
?>`

then in my <head> </head>

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href= "<?php echo $icon; ?>" />`